# There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented oauth2 with spring security and I am getting an error. Code is given below. I have saved user with encoded password using BcryptEncoder. And Bcrypt is also used in web security configuration to authorize user. I don't know why i am getting this error.

ServerSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/create/user").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

implentation UserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    public void save(User user) {
        Role role = roleDao.findByRole("superadmin").get();
        user.addRole(role);
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return (UserDetails) userDao.findByUsername(username).get();
    }
}
```

AuthrizationServer.java

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;
    @Autowired
    private AuthConfig config;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("pgcil").secret("secret").scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(18000);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token", config.getAuthPath());
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager).tokenStore(tokenStore()).accessTokenConverter(jwtTokenEnhancer());
        endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        System.out.println("token store");
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
    }

    /*
    Creating jwt token using .jks file in resources and keystore password
     */
    @Bean
    protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
        System.out.println("jwt token enhancer");
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"),
                config.getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwt"));
        return converter;
    }
}
```

and i getting an error when requesting the /oauth/token for token

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:244) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:198) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$LazyPasswordEncoder.matches(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:594) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:90) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:180) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

I am a beginner in spring. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to encode your secret in order to pass the authentication: add `{noop}`

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("pgcil").secret("{noop}secret").scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(18000);
    }
```